# Save activity data when switching to different activity in android like Whatsapp

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sharedpreferences, android-room

I am basically developing a chat app just like whatsapp, so I am also using **Room database** for persisting the chats for offline use. I store message delivered, seen, sent status with each message in database. So, if a user try to upload any media like then I want to show progressbar for file upload just like whatsapp, but where does whatsapp stores that download progress of each media message, because it seems they don't save it to Database because it's kind of **temporary** data and it changes very fast. Even when I switch from a person's chat to Chatlist in whatsapp aand go back to the person's chat I can see the upload bar there, so how does it maintain the state during activity switches.

I heard of using **sharedpreferences** and **saveinstance()** , but they are delivering some other functionality I think.

Answer (score 0):

Have look into:
[ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)  &  [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

The ViewModel keeps track of the state independent of what View is shown. And via LiveData you can update the current View. Since LiveData knows about the respective LifeCycle, it only updates the person's chat when it is currently active.